# How do I get Java to only look at the first letter like y or n?

Tags: java, equals

I am trying to get java to react to the answer regardless of the following letters I just want it to see "y/Y" or "n/N" and act accordingly. I want it to be able to recognize "yep" or "yeah" as opposed to "Yes" because they both begin with 'y'. How do I do that?

```
public static void reMatch(Scanner scan, Random rand, int gameCount, int 
totalCount) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
        String answer = scan.next();    
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            gameCount++;
            game(scan, rand, gameCount, totalCount);
        }
        else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            results(gameCount, totalCount);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `answer.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("y")`

Comment: `answer.toLowerCase().startsWith("y")`

Answer (score 2):

You need to test the value of first char in the string and act accordingly.

```
   if (answer.charAt(0)=='y' || answer.charAt(0)=='Y') {
        gameCount++;
        game(scan, rand, gameCount, totalCount);
    }
    else if (answer.charAt(0)=='n' || answer.charAt(0)=='N') {
        results(gameCount, totalCount);
    }
    else {
     //do something else
    }
```

Edit: I highly recommend you use `if (answer.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("y"))` instead as suggested by @Coldspeed

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
String firstChar = "" + answer.charAt(0);
if(firstChar.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
    ....
}
else if(firstChar.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ElliotFrisch said in his comment, you can make use of `startsWith`. Most answers that mean yes start with "ye," such as "yeah," "yep," or just plain "yes," so I would suggest something like this:

```
if (answer.toLowerCase().startsWith("ye")) {
    System.out.println("your answer stared with \"ye\"");
} else {
    System.out.println("your answer did not start with \"ye\"");
}
```

However you can also just use:

```
if (answer.toLowerCase().startsWith("y")) {
```

if you only want to test the first letter.

> P.S. Thanks Elliot Frisch!